# How to fix 403 error while displaying images from google drive?

Tags: google-chrome, google-drive-api

I am displaying around 20 thumbnail images at a time from google drive using the following link syntax, the thumbnail links are stored in a database and are grabbed using ajax `POST` request. I am testing this on localhost and every time i clear the cache and reload i get a `403 no response from server` error on at least a few images. The images are public and are made accessable to anyone and visiting the link manually opens the image every time.
Heres the link i use:

`"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/d/" + imgid + "=s500?authuser=0"`

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using this link to get the files?

Try to get one of the links in the [`File` resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files):

- **webContentLink** Link for downloading the content of the file in a browser. This is only available for files with binary content in Google Drive.
- **webViewLink** Link for opening the file in a relevant Google editor or viewer in a browser.
- **iconLink** Static, unauthenticated link to the file's icon.
- **thumbnailLink**    A short-lived link to the file's thumbnail, if available. Typically lasts on the order of hours. Only populated when the requesting app can access the file's content.

Choose one of the attributes that best fit your needs after that. Make the necessary request

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/<yout-file-id>?fields=webContentLink&key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
```

After that you can use your retrieved link to show the image.

There is on person having [your problem](https://issuetracker.google.com/149169004) if you want to look over the final result of the `img` tag.

Comment: i am aware that i can use the webContentLink in the src of the image, however that downloads the image in full res, i would like the thumbnails in a lesser quality than the actual image so they load faster. and the thumbnailLink is short lived and i am looking for a permanent approach.

Comment: In the end that is what Google API offer. You could just make an HTTP request to get the thumbnail links every time you need them. Or maybe upload the tumbnail version and the full resolution image to get whichever you want.